# Ubuntu drivers stop working all of a sudden

Tags: 16.04

i am using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS along with windows 7. Today while i was working in Ubuntu due to no power my laptop shutdown. later after getting the power i started the laptop again. now when i enter the Ubuntu my

- external mouse not working
- wired LAN is not showing
- wireless networking not showing
- display resolution shrinked
- no sound

have no idea what to do. thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Try a reboot. It could be that Ubuntu because corrupted due to the shutdown.

Comment: i rebooted several time(more than 10+). no change.